# The first letter of each <h3> into a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

Using **javascript** I'm looping through my H3 elements like this:

```
$('h3').each(function(){ });
```

I'm then generating an anchor for that tag formatted like this: "section-x" where x increments for each H3 on the page. The problem I have is that I'd like the first letter of the header to be an anchor link, like this:

**H**eading

.. where H is underlined, representing a link. I can format the anchors however I don't know how to wrap a hyperlink tag around the first letter in each heading. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
kvanberendonck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's throw some plain javascript into the mix:

```
$('h3').html(function(i){
    var self = $(this)
      , html = self.html()

    return html[0].anchor('section-'+i) + html.substring(1)
})
```

- `html` (and most other setter functions) accepts a function as an argument and uses the return value for each element
- `"string".link(target)` creates the code `<a href="#target">string</a>`. A nice vintage useful method

**edit:** switched from `.link` to `.anchor`. Anchors are deprecated though, you should start using IDs for that:

```
$('h3').html(function(i){
    var self = $(this)
      , text = self.text()

    // give the H3 an id and link to it
    // ideally the headers should already have an id
    this.id = 'section-'+i
    return text[0].link('#section-'+i) + text.substring(1)
})
```

Comment: +1 for `.link`, and for being the only one to remember the href.

Comment: For the anchors to work, I tried adding `self.name = 'section-'+i` but it didn't seem to do anything. How do I change the element name to the same name as the anchor so the pagelinks work?

Comment: You're missing a # in the link.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
$('h3').each(function(){ 
    var currentHeading = $(this).text();

    $(this).html("<a href='link'>" + currentHeading.substr(0,1) + "</a>" + currentHeading.substr(1, currentHeading.length - 1));
});
```

Comment: I believe it should be $(this).html() as text() would insert the html special chars equivalent of the anchor.

Comment: I think it only does that when you insert html into the .text()

Comment: If you use `$('h3').each(function(i){ ...`, index `i` can be used to build the sequential hrefs (`'section-' + i`)

Comment: Well look at the documentation for .text( textString ) and the example. see how the <b> tags are escaped

Comment: @Broncha right, if you did .html() you would end up having < as your first character. It seems to me like you would want them escaped in this situation.

Comment: @Broncha okay... i see what you mean now... not for the getting the text, but for setting it... duh, my bad

Comment: `c.substr(0,1)` === `c[0]` and `c.substr(1, c.length - 1)` === `c.substring(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h3').each(function(i){
   var firstLetter = $(this).text()[0];
   $(this).html('<a href="where.html">' + firstLetter + '</a>' + $(this).text().substr(1));
});
```

Not sure where you'd like to put `section-x` in that heading, but you can use `i` inside that `each()` to get the current iteration index.